# Looking for child content with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a phrase/author from the body of a URL. I can scrape the phrases but I don't know how to find the author and print it together with the phrase. Can you help me?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_url = "https://www.pensador.com/frases/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

for frase in soup.find_all("p", attrs={'class': 'frase fr'}):
    print(frase.text + '\n')

# author = soup.find_all("span", attrs={'class': 'autor'})
# print(author.text)
# this is the author that I need, for each phrase the right author
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the `parent` of the `p.frase.fr` tag, which is a `div`, and get the author by selecting `span.autor` descending the `div`:

```
In [1268]: for phrase in soup.select('p.frase.fr'):
      ...:     author = phrase.parent.select_one('span.autor')
      ...:     print(author.text.strip(), ': ', phrase.text.strip())
      ...:     
Roberto Shinyashiki :  Tudo o que um sonho precisa para ser realizado é alguém que acredite que ele possa ser realizado.
Paulo Coelho :  Imagine uma nova história para sua vida e acredite nela.
Carlos Drummond de Andrade :  Ser feliz sem motivo é a mais autêntica forma de felicidade.
...
...
```

Here, I'm using the CSS selector by `phrase.parent.select_one('span.autor')`, you can obviously use `find` here:

```
phrase.parent.find('span', attrs={'class': 'autor'})
```